# find all $a$ values such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n!)}{n^a} $ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

This is a question from my calculus class.

How can I  find all $a$ values such that the following series converges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n!)}{n^a} $$

I tried to use comparison test but did not find any candidates.

My work so far:

$$\frac{\log(n!)}{n^a}\le\frac{n\log(n)}{n^a}=\frac{\log(n)}{n^{a-1}}$$

$\frac{\log(n)}{n^{a-1}}$ Converges for $a>2$ and therefore  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n!)}{n^a}$ converges if $a > 2$.

What about $a < 2$?
I need some assistance with that case.

thanks!

Comment: What test do you use to know that $\log(n)\cdot n^{1-a}$ converges for $a\gt 2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n! \geq (n/2)^{n/2}$, thus $\frac{\log(n!)}{n^a} \geq \frac12\frac{\log(n/2)}{n^{a-1}}$, which implies that $a>2$ is necessary as well.

Comment: The OP should note that this takes care of $a=2$ as well (which wasn't mentioned in the OP).